# Uniswap v3: calculate tickLower and tickUpper

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

I want to create a pool on Uniswap V3 with a specific price. For example 1 Dev token eq 0.1 USDC, Dev token has 18 decimals and USDC has 6 decimals, code for create pool:

```
const POOL_FEE = 500

const sqrtPrice = uniswapSdk.encodeSqrtRatioX96(
  ethers.parseUnits('1', Devdecimals).toString(),
  ethers.parseUnits('0.1', USDCdecimals).toString(),
)

const result = await nonfungiblePositionManagerContract.createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary(
  USDCTokenAddress,
  DevTokenAddress,
  POOL_FEE,
  sqrtPrice.toString(),
)
```

I have tried this way, to calculate `tickLower` and `tickUpper`, but looks like it's not correct:

```
let CurrentTick = parseInt(poolData.tick);
let TickSpacing = parseInt(poolData.tickSpacing);
let NearestLowTick = (Math.floor( CurrentTick / TickSpacing )) * TickSpacing;
let NearestHighTick = ((Math.floor( CurrentTick / TickSpacing )) * TickSpacing) + TickSpacing;

const TicksForRange = 2;

let LowTick = (Math.floor( CurrentTick / TickSpacing )) * (TickSpacing - (TickSpacing * TicksForRange));
let HighTick = ((Math.floor( CurrentTick / TickSpacing )) * TickSpacing) + ( TickSpacing + ( TickSpacing * TicksForRange ));
```

```
const amountToApproveUSDC = ethers.parseUnits('100000', USDCdecimals)
const amountToApproveDev = ethers.parseUnits('1000000', Devdecimals)

const liquidityParams = {
  token0: USDCTokenAddress,
  token1: DevTokenAddress,
  fee: FeeAmount.LOW,
  tickLower: LowTick,
  tickUpper: HighTick,
  recipient: owner.address,
  amount0Desired: amountToApproveUSDC,
  amount1Desired: amountToApproveDev,
  amount0Min: 0,
  amount1Min: 0,
  deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 600,
}
```

But with such parameters I sent to the pool such amount of tokens:

```
1,000,000 Dev
144.744687 USDC
```

Can you tell me how I should calculate tickLower and tickUpper for this pool?